# linker error Undefined symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, bdmultidownloader

I use this [library](https://github.com/norsez/BDMultiDownloader/tree/master/Classes) to download files. But when I compile my project the linker throw me an error. The architecture is armv7.

[image]

The origin of this error is because I use:

```
[[BDMultiDownloader shared] queueRequest:[urlFolder stringByAppendingString:video] completion:^(NSData* data){
                [data writeToFile:file atomically:TRUE];
            }];
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you added the files to your project, was the target you are building ticked?

Select the `BDMultiDownloader.m` file in the project navigator in the left-hand sidebar, then select the file inspector in the right-hand sidebar.  Make sure that the target membership includes the target you are building.